# Grails Dependency Resolution

Tags: grails, dependency-management

I'm a bit of a Grails newbie. I have an app which works fine in Eclipse but when I deploy in production falls over because of missing dependencies.

When I run the dependency report it shows all the dependencies are automatically present for 'build' but absent for 'runtime'.

What's the neatest way to migrate the dependencies from to runtime so (I hope) they get copied into my war file?

Also, I'm using the sanitizer plugin. This runs fine in development but has the dependencies missing from 'runtime' so falls over. If I manually add, for example, one of the dependencies into BuildConfig.groovy ("org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:1.4.3") then grails falls over with this error:

loader constraint violation: loader (instance of ) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/xml/sax/SAXParseException"

I'm assuming that this is a classpath issue but I'm not sure why this only happens when I manually add the dependency - surely it's present all the time?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you have to add missing runtime dependencies to BuildConfig.groovy. The simplest thing would be to copy them from the plugin's BuildConfig.groovy to your app's one. You should also raise a JIRA for the respective grails plugin to get this fixed upstream.

Lots of jars out there in the Maven repositories have their dependencies not correctly defined in their pom file.
There is a way to fix that in BuildConfig.groovy, by switching off transitivity:

```
runtime('org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:1.4.3') {
   transitive = false
}
```

Instead of 'transitive=false' you might also experiment with excluding only specific dependencies using e.g.

```
excludes "xml-apis", "xerces"
```

inside the 'runtime' closure.

Comment: Excellent - thanks. It's a shame there's no way to get the dependencies into the runtime statement automatically instead of playing Sherlock Holmes to find them. The excludes statement sorts out my second problem. I just need to remember to add them in manually.